# How to speed up Finder on Yosemite

Tags: macos, finder

I have two MacBook Pros running Yosemite and both have an incredibly slow Finder. Finder was blazingly fast with Mavericks: as soon as I upgraded to Yosemite it became sluggish. When opening a folder, even a simple one, it takes seconds (from a few to some dozens) to display its content.

One MacBook Pro, 2011 non-retina, has a normal spinning hard drive: it takes ages for the Finder to display the files in a folder. Even if there are only a bunch of them, the spinning wheel stays spinning for too long. At the beginning I thought I had a faulty HD, but...

... the other MacBook Pro, even if a little dated (2008, the first unibody),  has an SSD hard drive. It was incredibly fast with Mavericks, overall slow on Yosemite. However, also on this computer the Finder spins the wheel for a very long time.

Both the computers were upgraded to Yosemite, none had a fresh installation of the OS. For me, Yosemite was like Vista for Windows users: perfectly usable computers became sluggish. I can live with a little slow MBP, but I cannot wait seconds each time I open a folder.

Is there anyone who had the same problem and could suggest a solution?

Comment: Honestly, I strongly cannot not recommend updating using the update function - from version to version you carry useless files with you, e.g. look at the size of your Library folder. Therefore I do Time Machine backups, backup my special and especially precious data on a separate drive, create an USB installer stick, boot from it, delete the harddisk, install a clean new system and copy my data back.

It also give me the opportunity to do some housekeeping and kick off unused software.

Comment: Antonio, see also my question. Is it related? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182293/troubleshooting-finder-and-disk-access-speeds-dropbox-extension-problems

Comment: @Garex I basically agree with your point of view: before Apple decided not to ship installer disks any more, I used to always do a fresh installation. But if the "orthodox" way of upgrading an OS is now via a network update, this update should be flawless.

Answer (score 1):

**Speed Up New Finder Window Generation by Changing All My Files**
All My Files is a smart folder that uses Spotlight to access any and all files owned by the current user. This can be great, but it can also slow down the generation of a new Finder window on some Macs. Changing the new Finder window to a static folder can help that speed:

- Pull down the Finder menu and choose “Preferences”
- Set the “New finder windows show” to “Desktop” or “Documents” or your
  user home folder

[image]

Close Finder preferences as usual

Comment: What does " a minimum number of data" mean

Comment: It means, you should change the default location for opening Finder windows to a folder with less items in it, e.g. an empty folder. :-) Hassle is, you need always to navigate to your new location. This is but a workaround and no real fix.

Comment: @Mark Please see my edited answer?

Comment: This is a cit and paste from somewhere please credit it

Comment: I have always had new Finder windows opening in my home folder, which is, even if "All my files" suggests the opposite, where all my files are, organized.